# Noob question regarding serializer Django

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have Customer model which has a foreign key for User model. I am trying to implement register feature as found below,
**Customer Model**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.username
```

**Customer and User serializers**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Customer
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'mobile']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Meta.depth = 1
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
         print(validated_data)
         mobile = validated_data.pop('mobile')
         print(mobile)
         serializer = UserSerializer(validated_data)
         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
         customer = models.Customer.objects.create(user=serializer.data, mobile=mobile)
         return customer
```

**RegisterAPIView**

```
class RegisterAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        customerSerializer = serializers.CustomerSerializer(data=data)
        customerSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

For me the create function of CustomerSerializer is not getting called. Am I missing something?

If I change my view to

```
class RegisterAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        userSerializer = serializers.UserSerializer(data=data)
        userSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        userSerializer.save()
        customerSerializer = serializers.CustomerSerializer(data=data)
        customerSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        customerSerializer.save()
        return Response(customerSerializer.data)
```

I get response data as "data":{"mobile":1111111111}, instead of the whole customer object (including user data). Also this creates possibility of User object being created without Customer object present (because of any issue while creating customer object)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

All this logic in the `CustomerSerializer` is not necessary, you can just use the `UserSerializer` as a "sub serializer":

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Customer
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'mobile']
```

---

> **Note**: Please *don't* store phone numbers as integer numbers. In "integer land", `0012345` and `12345` are the same, in "phone land", they might be different, especially since different countries have a different number of digits for phone numbers, it becomes close to impossible to format the phone number properly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1245990/67579) regarding the validation of phone numbers.